# Saving complex text string as an object in R

Tags: r, escaping, system

I'm trying to run this terminal command from within R using `system(mess)`:

```
mess <- "sed -i -e '62i\ \\\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}' intro-spatial-rl.tex"
```

But it keeps failing with the following error:

```
Error: '\u' used without hex digits in character string starting ""sed -i -e '62i\ \\\u"
```

I've seen `paste` used for system commands also, but this fails also.

Could use a different regex program, but thought this may be useful to others and improve my understanding of how R deals with characters. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the unequal number of `\` in your escape sequence.

R sees two escape sequences here: `\\` and `\u`. The second one is invalid and gives an error. You probably want to escape the second backslash as well, yielding `\\\\`. Likewise, you probably meant to escape the previous `\` in `\`  as well, leaving you with `\\` .

All that being said,  would replace the `sed` invocation completely by R code in this instance. The way I understand it you just want to insert a line of text. That’s easy in R (although it’s not clear what your input and output here is).

Comment: 6 backslashes for the simple output of \? Crazy but seems to work!